# C programming ! Arithmetic operator operation

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main()
{ 
    int a = 10, b = 5, c = 3; 
    b != !a; 
    c = !!a; 
    printf("%d\t%d", b, c); 
}
```

This is the c code. I got the output as 5    1 . I cant get the operation behind this expressions of b and c. Can anyone please explain how?

Comment: `!=` is not an assignment.

Comment: `!` is a *logical* negation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since a is initially 10, then `!a`  evaluates to `0`

Therefore `b != !a` evaluates to `5 != 0`, which evaluates to a true expression (`1`). (But as Michael points out in his answer, this is not an assignment operator).

`c = !!a` which evaluates to `c = !0`, which evaluates to `c = 1`

Explanation:
The language lawyers may scold me on this, but `!` operator applied to a non-zero expression evaluates to zero.  The `!` operator applied to any false (0) expression evaluates to 1.

Comment: Yes got it now. I thought != is same as like *= . So now b does not change.

Answer (score 2):

It's a trick question.

`b != !a;` is basically a NOP. It just evaluates to `1` but doesn't change the content of `b`. You can remove this line altogether and you'll get the same output.